# How to write JPARepository query where a query parameter is a list?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data

The documentation for Spring Data's `JPARepository` provides examples such as

```
List<User> findByLastname(String lastname);
```

for and SpringData will do all the work generating the proper query and the correct users will be returned.

But suppose I want to get 50 users and I have a list of their last names. I don't want to call the above method 50 times. I would like to call the JPA equivalent of

```
select *
from user
where last_name in ('N0', 'N1', 'N2'... 'N49');
```

Now looking at the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.9.x/reference/html/#dependencies) I see some possibilities such as named queries and specifications. The named queries seem to require specifying SQL in a Java annotation. The specifications used with the `findAll` methods have `is` and `hasMoreThan` type methods in the examples, but I don't see any that would turn into `in` queries. And the [Javadocs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/index.html?org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html) for specifications don't have any example usage.

How *does* one create a method in a `JPARepository` to query by a list of possibilities?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You use

```
List<User> findByLastnameIn(Collection<String> lastnames);
```

More [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation). (Table4, 5th to last row)

Comment: Impressive! I was hoping it would be that easy. Don't know how I missed that.

Comment: Isn't it Spring Data beautiful?

Answer (score 0):

Create an array of lastname that you want to make as query parameter. Then try this: findAllInLastName(List lastNames); The Spring data automatically search a suitable query method when you extend the JpaRepository class as long as you follow the right format of creating a query method name. Hope this helps you. And try to read the Spring Data online documentation. Cheers brother!